# How to return promise form controller to directive in angularjs using $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-resource, angular-directive, angular-controller

I want promise to be returned from controller to directive, as I want to change template based on promise received.

**LoginController :**

```
(function() {
  angular.module('nd')
    .controller('LoginController', loginController);

  function loginController(
    $scope,
    modelFactory,
    User,
    APPLICATION,
    REST_URL,
    $resource
    ) {

    $scope.user = modelFactory.create('user', User);

    $scope.login = login;

    function login() {
      var resource = $resource(APPLICATION.host + REST_URL.login);
      var promise = resource.save($scope.user);
      return promise;
    }
  }
})();
```

**Button Directive :**

```
(function() {
  angular.module('nd')
    .directive('ndButton', button);

  function button() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        ndLable: '@',
        ndClick: '&'
      },
      templateUrl: '../components/fields/button/button.template.html',
      link: link
    };

    function link(scope) {
      scope.clickButton = function() {
        var promise = scope.ndClick();
        promise.$promise.then(function(user) {
          console.log(user);
        });
      };
    }
  }
})();
```

**login.html :**

```
<form ng-submit="login()">
  <div class="input-container">
    <nd-text-box
      ng-model="user.username"
      nd-lable="Username"
      nd-id="Username"
      nd-required="required"></nd-text-box>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <nd-password
      ng-model="user.password"
      nd-lable="Password"
      nd-id="Password"
      nd-required="required"></nd-password>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <nd-button nd-lable="Go"></nd-button>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></div>
</form>
```

**button template :**

```
<button ng-click="clickButton()">
  <span>{{ndLable}}</span>
</button>
```

In directive, at `scope.ndClick()`, it is calling function `login()` of controller. In controller, I'm getting `promise` as `{ $promise: Promise, $resolved: false }`.
I'm returning `promise` back in directive, but in directive I'm getting promise as undefined.

Comment: can you show the login template where you are using the directive?

Comment: @war1oc, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

login.html

```
<div class="button-container">
    <nd-button nd-lable="Go" ndClick="login()"></nd-button>
</div>
```

Bind the `$scope.login` method to `ndClick`

Comment: It works...Can you explain me why ng-submit didn't work...?

Comment: `ng-submit` will work if you have an input with `type="submit"`. You also have to send the function to the directive so it binds with `&` so you can later call the function from your directive controller.

Answer (score 1):

I cant tell you why you receive undefined as a return value. I created a fiddle and got the same result. I think it's a scope issue. Maybe some else can explain it. However i would suggest to use a factory or a service to store the user data, so you're able to use it in your whole application. Here is a fiddle which use a factory to share data between several controller and a directive/component: https://jsfiddle.net/trollr/rjuvagb9/

Otherwise you can add an additional two way binding to your directive scope to synchronize the data.

```
function button() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ndLable: '@',
      ndClick: '&', 
      ndPromise: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '../components/fields/button/button.template.html',
    link: link
};
```

Template:

```
<button nd-promise="loginPromise" nd-click"login()">..</button>
```

Controller:

```
function login() {
  var resource = $resource(APPLICATION.host + REST_URL.login);
  $scope.loginPromise = resource.save($scope.user).$promise;
}
```

Comment: I want to change button template based on promise, so I want promise in directive so that I can easily change the template.

Comment: Change my answer. Just pass the promise `resource.save($scope.user).$promise` into data and it should work as expected. Maybe ndData is the wrong name.

Comment: Nice trick, I will definitely use this if I won't be able to fix 'return undefined' issue.